# "glad to write to you again" vs "pleased to contact you again"

Tags: expressions, greetings

I would like to write an email to one of my friend, who I did not contact for a long time. So, is it OK in English to say:

> I am **glad** to write to you again.

or

> I am **pleased** to write to you again.

Which one is more polite and correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question reminds me of another ELL question I've seen, one that asks about the difference between ["urgent" and "a bit urgent"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/219348/which-is-more-formal-bit-urgent-or-urgent).

I find these two questions interesting because you are asking about which of your options is more polite and correct, and I see it as more of a matter of formality, whereas the other question asked about which option is more formal, whereas I think it's more a matter of politeness.

In other words, both of your options are equally correct and equally polite. Where they differ is in their formality.

> I am pleased to write to you again.

sounds very formal. I would be more likely to use this kind of language if I was writing a dignitary rather than a friend.

> I am glad to write to you again.

is less formal, but still not chummy. I might use this when emailing a colleague.

If I was writing someone I considered to be a good friend, I'd probably use something more along the lines of:

> I'm so happy to be writing you again.

This is more emotive and suggests a close friendship.

However, you mention in your question that you have not corresponded with this friend for quite some time. That being the case, perhaps you don't want to sound too excited. I think your second option might be a good one to go with:

> I am glad to be writing you again.

You might add the word *finally*, if you want to suggest you wish you could have written sooner:

> I'm glad to finally be writing you again.